# How do you create a timeout but continue scenario in WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a "logout" endpoint, for the most part I don't really care what the user enters but I want to "penalize" if they entered an invalid token so there's a check, but that check may take a while on load and I want to limit it to 3 seconds, but let it continue processing in the background.

The code block I have looks like this...

```
    return claimsService
        .revoke(request.getToken(), serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders())
        .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(authProperties.getRevokeProcessingTimeoutInMillis()))
        .doOnNext(
            serviceResponse -> {
              final var serverHttpResponse = serverWebExchange.getResponse();
              addCommonHeaders(serverHttpResponse);
              serverHttpResponse.setStatusCode(serviceResponse.getStatusCode());
            })
        // on security error just return ok and add penalty
        .onErrorResume(
            SecurityException.class,
            ex ->
                Mono.just(GatewayResponse.builder().ok(true).build())
                    .delayElement(
                        Duration.ofMillis(authProperties.getPenaltyDelayInMillis()),
                        penaltyScheduler))
        .onErrorResume(TimeoutException.class, ex1 -> respondWithOk(serverWebExchange))
        .subscribeOn(logoutScheduler);
```

The problem is when TimeoutException is fired the revocation code stops as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mono.firstWithSignal()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#firstWithSignal-reactor.core.publisher.Mono...-) or [Mono.firstWithValue()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#firstWithValue-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono...-) would take two publishing sources and return the first one that responds.  However, still completes the monos.

In my scenario, the output will be the same regardless (basically an OK response), but even if it is not it's not relevant as long as a response was sent.

In which case I just need two monos, one with the original and no timeout

```
    final var logoutFromService =
        claimsService
            .revoke(request.getToken(), serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders())
            .doOnNext(
                serviceResponse -> {
                  final var serverHttpResponse = serverWebExchange.getResponse();
                  addCommonHeaders(serverHttpResponse);
                  serverHttpResponse.setStatusCode(serviceResponse.getStatusCode());
                })
            .flatMap(this::addDelaySpecifiedInServiceResponse)
            // on security error just return ok and add penalty
            .onErrorResume(
                SecurityException.class,
                ex ->
                    Mono.just(GatewayResponse.builder().ok(true).build())
                        .delayElement(
                            Duration.ofMillis(authProperties.getPenaltyDelayInMillis()),
                            penaltyScheduler));
```

And another that just says okay with a delay that was the previous timeout.

```
    final var timeout =
        Mono.just(GatewayResponse.builder().ok(true).build())
            .delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(authProperties.getRevokeProcessingTimeoutInMillis()));
```

Then combine them with [Mono.firstWithValue()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#firstWithValue-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono...-).  Since I don't want to display any error to the end user.

```
    return Mono.firstWithValue(logoutFromService, timeout);
```

Here it is in my [controller code](https://github.com/trajano/spring-cloud-demo/blob/de4081a92977f7c3b27884e2c124c0c61824654e/gateway/src/main/java/net/trajano/swarm/gateway/auth/AbstractAuthController.java#L179-L223)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is any more idiomatic way to do this but you can use `cache()` operator to split the flow.

I've used some simplified code to demonstrate:

```java
Mono<String> result = Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(4))
    .thenReturn("late result")
    .cache();

result.doOnNext(x -> System.out.println("Async result: " + x))
            .doOnError(e -> System.out.println("async error"))
            .subscribe();

return result.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
    .onErrorResume(TimeoutException.class, /*fallback*/)
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  Though the `subscribe` in the middle looks a bit odd it seems to make sense in the scenario though.

Comment: you don't really need `subscribe` here

Comment: @Alex you do need it I believe, otherwise the async flow is not triggered

Comment: of course at some point you need to subscribe to reactive sequence but in most cases this is anti-pattern and better to avoid calling subscribe explicitly

Comment: @Alex so you are saying there's a better approach for this problem? Can you share it?